# Monkey-patching Python SSL package with QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am creating a plugin which interacts with a third-party API (through the package [ArlulaApi](https://pypi.org/project/arlulaapi/)). At some point in my package tree (for the plugin), `gevent` is imported, meaning that a monkey patch is required for the Python `SSL` package to work correctly (otherwise, `RecursionError` is thrown - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49820173/requests-recursionerror-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded)). Currently, I am trying this at the very top of my plugin code:

```
import gevent.monkey
gevent.monkey.patch_socket()
gevent.monkey.patch_ssl()
```

However, this throws a warning:

> Monkey-patching ssl after ssl has already been imported may lead to
> errors, including RecursionError on Python 3.6. It may also silently
> lead to incorrect behaviour on Python 3.7. Please monkey-patch
> earlier. See https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/1016. Modules
> that had direct imports (NOT patched): ['urllib3.util
> (C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\**init**.py)',
> 'urllib3.util.ssl_
> (C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py)'].

It appears that SSL is imported when QGIS boots up, before my plugin is loaded, and so the monkey patching does not have the desired effect.

What are my options here?

Am I missing something really obvious?

Are there ways to monkey patch earlier, or do I have to create a plugin that does not require monkey patching?

Comment: Did you try to execute your block code in `startup.py` to try enforcing the SSL monkey patching e.g https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#running-python-code-when-qgis-starts?

Comment: I believe that will work, but I aim to make this plugin publicly available - am I able to create/edit a user's `startup.py` file on plugin installation?

Comment: No, it may overwrite an existing `startup.py` and you would need to restart QGIS after plugin install